# Magento 2 EE: How can I disable certain B2B emails?

Tags: magento2, email, b2b

I have a Magento 2.2.4 store with the B2B extension installed.

I am looking to **disable** some of the emails for which you can set templates in

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Company Configuration

How can I **add an admin setting** to **disable** the sending of these emails like you see in the

> Sales > Sales Emails settings

Answer (score 0):

To disable certain B2B emails:

1. Add a preference to your module's Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml file to extend the class responsible for sending B2B emails like:

```
    <preference for="Magento\Company\Model\Email\Sender" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Email\SenderOverride" />
```

2. In Vendor\Module\Model\Email\SenderOverride, Override the function that sends the email like:

```
    public function sendAssignSuperUserNotificationEmail(CustomerInterface $customer, $companyId)
    {
        // don't send email
        return $this;
    }
```

If you desire to have this functionality controlled by an admin setting, then you will need to create the following files and lookup the setting in "Vendor\Module\Model\Email\SenderOverride"

- Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\system.xml
- Vendor\Module\etc\config.xml

Please reference the Adobe [Experience League](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/files/config-reference-systemxml.html?lang=en) docs for more info on these files.